# Dragged Images Property inside canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drag-and-drop, opacity

I have a drag n drop feature in my canvas, and i have many Images in it. I want to change opacity of the image i just clicked and apparently it worked. However when i click 2 or more images and change the opacity, all the images that are clicked are changed as well. I just want the last image that i clicked that is changed.

here is my code :

```
private void CanvasLayout_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var image = e.Source as Image;

    if (image != null && CanvasLayout.CaptureMouse())
    {
        mousePosition = e.GetPosition(CanvasLayout);
        draggedImage = image;
        Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 1);

        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (draggedImage.Name == "Image" + i)
            {
                SelectComp_ComboBox.SelectedValue = "0" + (i + 1);

                Binding binding = new Binding
                {
                    Source = TransHidden_textBox,
                    Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
                };
                draggedImage.SetBinding(ContentControl.OpacityProperty, binding);
            }
        }
    }
}
private void CanvasLayout_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (draggedImage != null)
    {
        CanvasLayout.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 0);
        draggedImage = null;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in this line `draggedImage.SetBinding(ContentControl.OpacityProperty, binding);` that i need to change the `draggedImage` to `Image + i` but i don't know how to change `string` to `Image`.

How can i do that? is there any other easy way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the code you provided but I guess you're not clearing the opacity binding for items that are no longer dragged. You should call

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(noLongerDraggedImage, ContentControl.OpacityProperty);
```

in order to do that, where `noLongerDraggedImage` is (obviously) a reference to the image that is no longer dragged. Depending on your code you could either do that in a method that handles the end of dragging (be that drop or cancellation), or, alternatively, you could iterate over all images except for `draggedImage` at the beginning of your `CanvasLayout_MouseLeftButtonDown` method. Note though that in the latter case the last dragged image will have different opacity until another image is dragged, and that is not standard behavior.

**EDIT**

Since you've provided the code for `CanvasLayout_MouseLeftButtonUp` method, for all I know putting the aforementioned line in it:

```
private void CanvasLayout_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (draggedImage != null)
    {
        CanvasLayout.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 0);
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(draggedImage, ContentControl.OpacityProperty);
        draggedImage = null;
    }
}
```

should get you the expected result.

**EDIT II**

I'm not sure I understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish here, so perhaps i'll be best to take a step back and answer your question - how to get hold of an image with a specific name. One possibility would be to find it in `Canvas.Children` collection:

```
var name = "Image" + i.ToString();
var imageX = CanvasLayout.Children.OfType<Image>().Single(i => i.Name == name);
```

Note that using [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb920325(v=vs.90).aspx) method is only safe when you're certain that there's exactly one image with the given name in the collection, otherwise an exception will be thrown. If it's not the case you should consider using either [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918963(v=vs.90).aspx) - if there will be one or none image with matching name, or [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb920047(v=vs.90).aspx) - for any number of images with matching names.

Comment: I edit my code with `CanvasLayout_MouseLeftButtonDown` provided. I tried to use `ClearBinding` in `CanvasLayout_MouseLeftButtonDown` but its error because the image is null. i still don't understand how to do it

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i did it but with that code the opacity only change when i hold the mouse down. I think the best solution is to get the `draggedImage` name by String `Image + i` but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was the goal... Ok, so before I update my answer please confirm if I get you right - you want to apply custom opacity to an image upon clicking it, and upon clicking another one revert the previously clicked one to normal?

Comment: yeah yeah i mean, with your code, when i click another image, the first image lose the new value of opacity, like its not saved because the binding is cleared.